# flash as2 tween loop

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to make tween menu items in order. How can I do this in for loop?. I do not wanna do it manually.

Thanks for answers.

My Code;

```
var open_menuTween0:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+0+"_mc"], "_y", Regular.easeIn, -20,0.05,0.2, true);
open_menuTween0["onMotionFinished"] = function(){
var open_menuAlpha0:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+0+"_mc"], "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0,100,0.2, true);
var open_menuTween1:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+1+"_mc"], "_y", Regular.easeIn, 0.05,44.15,0.2, true);
open_menuTween1["onMotionFinished"] = function(){
var open_menuAlpha1:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+1+"_mc"], "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0,100,0.2, true);
var open_menuTween2:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+2+"_mc"], "_y", Regular.easeIn, 44.15,88.25,0.2, true);
open_menuTween2["onMotionFinished"] = function(){
var open_menuAlpha2:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+2+"_mc"], "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0,100,0.2, true);
var open_menuTween3:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+3+"_mc"], "_y", Regular.easeIn,88.25,132.35,0.2, true);
open_menuTween3["onMotionFinished"] = function(){
var open_menuAlpha3:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+3+"_mc"], "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0,100,0.2, true);
var open_menuTween4:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+4+"_mc"], "_y", Regular.easeIn,132.35,176.45,0.2, true);
open_menuTween4["onMotionFinished"] = function(){
var open_menuAlpha4:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+4+"_mc"], "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0,100,0.2, true);
var open_menuTween5:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+5+"_mc"], "_y", Regular.easeIn,176.45,220.55,0.2, true);
open_menuTween5["onMotionFinished"] = function(){
var open_menuAlpha5:Tween = new Tween(_root.menu_tab_mc["menu"+5+"_mc"], "_alpha", Regular.easeIn, 0,100,0.2, true);
}   
}   

}   

}   
}               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TweenMax and TimelineMax](http://www.greensock.com/v12/) instead - they allow sequencing, joining, reversing animations and much more